# What's the input size that appears in the runtime complexity of integer remainder and division?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, cpu, division, integer-division

I'm trying to figure out the runtime complexity of remainder and division for integers in modern computers. Regardless of the algorithm used, I often find the input size being defined as the number of bits used to store the integers being divided. I find that definition to be ambiguous. Assume one of the numbers being divided is 10: it can be stored with 4 bits. However, from a programmer's perspective, if 10 is stored in a variable of type int and in the programming language being used ints are represented with, say, 32 bits, 10 will be stored using 32 bits. In the aforementioned example, which value represents the input size that appears in the runtime complexity? 4 bits or 32 bits?

Comment: The question is confusing: changing the input size doesn't affect runtime complexity, because runtime complexity describes how the runtime changes with regard to the input size, not vice versa.

Comment: @ihonen Thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the aforementioned example, which value represents the input size that appears in the runtime complexity? 4 bits or 32 bits?

The input size is the number of bits the ALU performing the operation takes in (or more specifically, how many bits the algorithm within the ALU operates on) - it is entirely dependent on the CPU architecture and the code produced by you or your compiler.

Technically speaking, there is nothing preventing you from designing a CPU that has 32-bit registers and an 8-bit ALU that is able to accept only the least significant 8 bits of a register as its input (granted, such a CPU would be utterly unbearable to work with, but it would be entirely possible). And if there were multiple ALUs, say, 8-bit and 64-bit, there is nothing preventing you or the compiler from using whichever you like assuming the instruction set architecture grants you such a freedom.

It is impossible to give a universal answer to your question, because it is not tied to any implementation in particular.